# How to simulate multiple targets in FMCW radar simulation in python?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, signal-detection, radar, signal-synthesis

I have simulated a FMCW radar for a single stationary target, now the next step in my project is to simulate multiple moving targets. For this I had thought of using doppler shift to show a difference in received frequecy, but for some reason after calculating the effective frequency the values of frequency for different targets remains the same. even though the doppler shift values are different.

Below is the code for Simulation of FMCW radar used by me(single target)

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from math import pi

    chirp_duration = 60e-6
    f0 = 1e6 
    f1 = 10e6 
    no_samp = 8001
    target_range = 3e3
    bandwidth = f1 - f0
    c = 3e8

    f_step = (f1-f0)/no_samp

    #received signal freq
    rf_axis = np.arange(f0, f1, f_step)
    rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, len(rf_axis))

    rchirp = np.cos(2 * np.pi * rf_axis * rt_axis)

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3))
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.title('Received Chirp')
    plt.plot(rt_axis, rchirp)
    plt.show()

    # transmtted signal
    slope = bandwidth/no_samp
    time_delay = 2*target_range/c
    change_in_frequency = slope * time_delay
    frequency_at_time = f0 + change_in_frequency

    # Define f_axis
   tf_axis = np.linspace(frequency_at_time, f1, int(f_step))

    # Define t_axis
    tt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, int(f_step))
    changed_axis = tt_axis + time_delay

    # Create chirp
    tchirp = np.cos(2 * np.pi * tf_axis * tt_axis)

    # Plot chirp
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3))
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    plt.title('Transmitted Chirp')
    plt.plot(changed_axis, tchirp)
    plt.show()
```

For simulation of FMCW radar for multiple targets I have onl used the received chirp part as that's where the changes will happen.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    chirp_duration = 60e-6
    f0 = 1e6
    f1 = 10e6
    no_samp = 8001
    c = 3e8

    f_step = (f1 - f0) / no_samp
    rf_axis = np.arange(f0, f1, f_step)
    rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, len(rf_axis))

    # Define target parameters
    target_ranges = [3e3, 5e3, 8e3]  # Distances to the targets in meters
    target_velocities = [10, 5, 15]  # Velocities of the targets in m/s

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))

    # Plot the received chirp signal for each target
    for i in range(len(target_ranges)):
        # Calculate the Doppler shift for the current target
        doppler_shift = 2 * target_velocities[i] / c * rf_axis

        # Apply the Doppler shift to the chirp signal for the current target
        rchirp = np.cos(2 * np.pi * (rf_axis + doppler_shift) * rt_axis)

        # Create a subplot for the current target
        plt.subplot(len(target_ranges), 1, i + 1)
        plt.plot(rt_axis, rchirp)
        plt.xlabel("Time")
        plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
        plt.title(f"Received Chirp for Target {i + 1}")

    # Adjust the spacing between subplots
    plt.tight_layout()

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```

**The updated code is given below.**

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Parameters
    chirp_duration = 60e-6
    f0 = 1e6
    f1 = 10e6
    no_samp = 8001
    c = 3e8

    # Frequency axis
    f_step = (f1 - f0) / no_samp
    rf_axis = np.arange(f0, f1, f_step)
    rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, len(rf_axis))

    # Define target parameters
    target_ranges = [3e3, 5e3, 8e3]  # Distances to the targets in meters
    target_velocities = [30, 40, 50]  # Velocities of the targets in m/s

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))

    # Plot the received chirp signal for each target
    for i in range(len(target_ranges)):
    # Calculate the phase shift for the current target
    phase_shift = -2 * np.pi * (f1-f0) * 2 * target_velocities[i] / c

    # Apply the phase shift to the received chirp signal for the 
    current target
    rchirp = np.cos((2 * np.pi * rf_axis * rt_axis) + phase_shift)
    print('rchirp',rchirp)

    # Create a subplot for the current target
    plt.subplot(len(target_ranges), 1, i + 1)
    plt.plot(rt_axis, rchirp)
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    plt.title(f"Received Chirp for Target {i + 1}")

    # Adjust the spacing between subplots
    plt.tight_layout()

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```

[image: the output of the new code]

Comment: @V.V.T or I thought that instead I'll just simulate by using the phase shift caused ny caused by the doppler shift due to change in frequency...new code is added in the question

Comment: You never calculate the received frequency; you simply plot the transmitted and received chirps. I guess you hope to see the Doppler shift by inspecting and comparing visually the graphs. Visual comparison is hardly possible even with the velocities of your updated code. With the target velocity of 50 m/s, $v=50$, the Doppler shift is $f_d = f_{received}-f_{transmitted} = 2v·f_{transmitted}/(c/n-v) \approx 2·50/(299792548/1.000293-50) \approx 100/299704594.54 \approx 0.00000033366$

Comment: Can you notice the frequency variation as small as a 1/3 millionth part in the plot with bitmap resolution of even as great as 4K? To simulate the Doppler shift measurement, use triangular modulation. Plot the graph of chirp frequency vs. time and use frequencies at the rising/falling edges of this graph to compute. See formulas and discussion of what modulation type is required for the Doppler shift measurement, for example, in *Frequency-Modulated Continuous-Wave Radar (FMCW Radar)* tutorial https://www.radartutorial.eu/02.basics/Frequency%20Modulated%20Continuous%20Wave%20Radar.en.html .

Comment: with the updated code the shift in the frequency is not quite visible but the phase shift is quite clearly visible

Comment: @V.V.T int he new code I didn't even calculate the doppler shift in frequency I directly calculated the phase shift yhat would be caused by the doppler shift. Now after reading your previous comments I am starting to think that the method followed by me is not right??

Comment: @V.V.T dont you think that I am here because I am new to this field

Comment: See a 'crash course' on FMCW radar basics in my answer. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For students with special needs who prefer to learn via coding (like me and maybe you), the perfect option is to find a Jupyter notebook on FMCW radar basics. Having failed to find one, I'm writing an answer under the guise of Jupyter, with intermittent pieces of Python code, formulas, and explanatory text. Hope this helps.

Let us start with the problems which a FMCW radar is intended to solve. When characterizing detection-and-ranging technologies like lidar, radar, sonar, 'ranging' names a technique to measure distances. Regardless of medium (outer space, air, water) and carrier (light, radio waves, sound waves) used, we have a template code to process the sensor data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal 

c = 10.0 # speed of carrier waves (light, radio, sound) in medium (outer space, air, water)
samplerate = 2000
# search web with 'radar equation' keyword to understand the meaning of the expression below
radar_eq_coeff = 1 #[squaremeter] = [antenna gain] * [cross section] * [antenna area] * [efficiency]

def recvd_sig(radar_sends, distance):
    delayval = 2 * np.int_(distance * samplerate / c)
    prefix = np.zeros(delayval)
    return (np.sqrt(radar_eq_coeff) / (4 * np.pi) / distance**2) * np.append(prefix, radar_sends)

duration = 5
time = np.linspace(0,duration,samplerate*duration, endpoint= False)

sqeaktime = 0.5
dist = 1.25

squeak = np.zeros(len(time))
# send 0.1 s pulse
for i in range(samplerate//10):
    squeak[np.int_(samplerate*sqeaktime) + i] = 1.0

# receive echo
echo = recvd_sig(squeak, dist)[:len(time)]

plt.figure('Range: sqeak, echo')
plt.plot(time, squeak, label='radar sends')
plt.plot(time, echo, label='receives echo')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The only specification in this code is the radar equation coefficient used to give an amplitude of the signal reflected from the target. It may become important when studying radars, but for now this amplitude can be safely set to unity.

The parameter values are purely arbitrary and chosen only to provide signal waveforms conveniently shown with plots. The function `recvd_sig(radar_sends, distance)` is defined with the only purpose to represent the physical arrangement in the program flow: the radar transmitter sends the pulse (`squeak`) which is reflected from the target (`echo = recvd_sig(squeak, dist)`), the distance between the radar and the target `dist = 1.25` is passed as a parameter in the recvd_sig function call. The coder is free to unwrap this call to inline operators in the course of further code development.

As this code is a learning aid, I ain't attaching the plot output.

Given the transmitted pulse and the received echo timing data, the distance is calculated as the delay between these signals times the speed of carrier wave. The 'ranging' part can be solved in this way.

Two distance values dist(t1), dist(t2) measured at times t1, t2 seem to enable us to calculate the velocity using the velocity definition: v = (dist(t2)-dist(t1))/(t2-t1). However, the precision of this velocity measurement technique is poor, and the velocity value measured in this way is not instantaneous by definition (is it v(t1)? or v(t2)? or v((t1+t2)/2)?). Detection-and-ranging techniques enable us to measure the target velocity directly, using the Doppler effect.

See a template code where the sensor data is processed for velocity measurement using the Doppler effect:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal 

c = 10.0
samplerate = 2000

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal 

c = 10.0
samplerate = 2000

# target with POSITIVE velocity WITHDRAWS from the radar
# I omit the echo amplitude change here
# for light waves, this is only valid for target_velocity << c
# the exact Doppler shift for light waves is sqrt((1+beta)/(1-beta)); beta = target_velocity / c
def recvd_sig(radar_sends, target_velocity):
    sample_count = len(radar_sends)
    dopplershifted_sample_count = np.int_(sample_count * (c + target_velocity) / (c - target_velocity))
    return signal.resample(radar_sends, dopplershifted_sample_count)
    
freq = 10
duration = 1
time = np.linspace(0,duration,samplerate*duration, endpoint= False)

wave = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * time)
velocity = -0.1 # target with negative velocity APPROACHES the radar

echo = recvd_sig(wave, velocity)[:len(time)]
# set signal durations to min(len(wave),len(echo))
if (len(echo) < len(time)):
    time = time[:len(echo)]
    wave = wave[:len(echo)]

# plot wave and echo
plt.figure('Doppler: wave, echo' )
plt.title('Doppler shift, (target velocity)/c = %f' % (velocity/c))
plt.plot(time, wave, label='radar sends')
plt.plot(time, echo, label='receives echo')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

With this great ratio value of 'target velocity'-to-'carrier wave speed' (abs(velocity/10) = 0.1/10 = 0.01) as in this piece of code, had `c` be the light speed, `velocity` would have to be 0.01*300,000km/s = 3,000km/s, that is, 375 times the velocity of an LEO satellite. Of course, the frequency variation for this great target velocity is visible by inspection in the 'Doppler shift, target velocity = 0.1' plot, but for Earth-bound targets you cannot expect that the effect visibility is also pronounced in the graphs, and it is not.

The comment near the `recvd_sig` function def is a stipulation about a relativistic Doppler effect. This comment can be ignored for measurements with Earth-bound objects, but it is necessary to respect possible rigorous reviewers of this post.

Also, I omit the radar-equation factor in the amplitude of the reflected wave which is not essential for our consideration; the amplitude of the reflected wave is unity.

So, we need a continuous wave ('CW' in the 'FMCW' abbreviation) to measure target velocities, but the pure-sine continuous wave cannot be used to measure distances ('ranging'). The solution is to use a MODULATED continuous wave.

Had we have a means to attach a parameter to the continuous wave which makes it possible to carry this data with the wave, we would be able to calculate the delay between the moment t1, when this piece of data is transmitted, and the moment t2, when this piece of data is received after performing a round trip from the radar (lidar, sonar) to the target and back to the radar (lidar, sonar). At the same time, the wave, being a continuous wave, makes it possible to measure the instantaneous velocity of the target.

As it turns out, the necessary parameter can be attached in the form of instantaneous frequency, using a FREQUENCY MODULATION technique ('FM' in the 'FMCW' abbreviation). It is what the 'chirps' in your code are for.

To be sure that marking the continuous wave followed by mark reading is possible, examine the code where an CW wave is first modulated (`xmit_wave = np.sin(np.pi*2*(fcarrier*time + message_integral/samplerate))`) and then demodulated (`analytic_xmit = signal.hilbert(xmit_wave); inst_freq = np.diff(np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_xmit)))*samplerate/(2*np.pi)`), thus recovering the sawtooth waveform (`message`) used to frequency-modulate a sine wave `sin(np.pi*2*(fcarrier*time)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal 

samplerate = 1600
fcarrier = 15
duration = 5
fmax = fcarrier + 20
time = np.linspace(0,duration,samplerate*duration, endpoint= False)
# a message used to frequency-modulate the continuous wave
message = (fmax-fcarrier)*(signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*time)+1)/2.0

# integrate the frequency modulating signal (message) over time
# to arrive at the variable phase following the principle of frequency modulation
message_integral = np.cumsum(message)

# FM wave; chirp from fcarrier to fmax
xmit_wave = np.sin(np.pi*2*(fcarrier*time + message_integral/samplerate))

plt.figure('chirp')
plt.plot(time, xmit_wave)
plt.show()

# recover instantaneous frequency
# first make the signal analytic
analytic_xmit = signal.hilbert(xmit_wave)
# instantaneous frequency is the derivative of analytic signal's phase ('angle')
inst_freq = np.diff(np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_xmit)))*samplerate/(2*np.pi)

plt.figure('instantaneous frequency')
plt.title('recovered msg; chirp from f_carrier = %g, to f_max = %g' % (fcarrier, fmax))
plt.plot(time, message, label='message')
plt.plot(time[:len(time)-1], inst_freq, label='inst_freq = message + f_carrier')
plt.legend(loc="right")
plt.show()
```

This code processes the *transmitted* wave and therefore serves only as a feasibility proof. In the working program, you have to process **the signal from the radar receiver**.

In the explanation that follows, I assume that FM modulation/demodulation is performed elsewhere, and the function `recvd_signal(radar_sends, target_distance, target_velocity)` returns a decoded FM-demodulated message which the transmitter has encoded in the radar-emitted chirp.

This code is intended to perform ranging and velocity measurement in one batch. Only the speed-of-light parameter value, 300,000 km/s, is real; selection of the other parameter values is dictated by the convenience considerations of graphic presentation. In reality, the carrier frequency is much greater than 1MHz. However, using this code, the learner can see how the target distance is calculated from measurement data of how the message sawtooth is shifted in a **horizontal** direction, and the target velocity is calculated from measurement data of how the message sawtooth is shifted in a **vertical** direction:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal 

c = 3E5 # 300,000 km/s
samplerate = 300000
carrier_frequency = 1E6 # 1MHz
# target with POSITIVE velocity WITHDRAWS from the radar
# for light waves, this Doppler shift formula is approximate and only valid for target_velocity << c
# the exact Doppler shift for light waves is sqrt((1+beta)/(1-beta)); beta = target_velocity / c
# Also, I omit the echo amplitude change here
def recvd_signal(radar_sends, target_distance, target_velocity):
    sample_count = len(radar_sends)
    delayval = 2 * np.int_(target_distance * samplerate / c)
    message_truncated = radar_sends[:(sample_count - delayval)]
    reflected_message_prefix = np.zeros(delayval)
    message_shifted = np.append(reflected_message_prefix, message_truncated) - carrier_frequency * 2 * target_velocity / (c - target_velocity)
    return message_shifted
    
duration = 0.001 # 1ms
distance = 3 # 3km
time = np.linspace(0,duration,np.int_(samplerate*duration), endpoint= False)
sawtooth_freq = 5000 # 5KHz

message = (signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*time*sawtooth_freq)+1)/2.0
velocity = -0.01 # -10m/s. Target with negative velocity APPROACHES the radar

echo = recvd_signal(message, distance, velocity)

# plot wave and echo
plt.figure('Ranging, Doppler measurements' )
plt.title('distance = %g km, velocity = %g km/s' % (distance, velocity))
plt.plot(time, message, label='radar sends')
plt.plot(time, echo, label='receives echo')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.show()
```

However graphic the code output may be, I recommend you take a look at the radar hardware working principles. The radar chip-and-system manufacturers generously enlighten us about this technology. See, for example, [Renesas blogs](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/blogs/basics-fmcw-radar) and application notes of Texas Instruments and Infineon.